# STB Reason:Can't open

Tags: deep-learning

I'm training a system with `YOLO darknet` on random dataset. But it is not able to open files. Here it showing some error.

```
STB Reason: can't fopen
Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO): /home/kalyan/darknet/data/NFPA_datasetpos-218.txt 
Can't open label file. (This can be normal only if you use MSCOCO): /home/kalyan/darknet/data/NFPA_datasetpos-279.txt 
Cannot load image "/home/darknet/data/NFPA_datasetpos-289.jpg"
STB Reason: can't fopen
Cannot load image "/home/darknet/data/NFPA_datasetpos-58.jpg"
```